# How to use configuration file (openapitools.json) with @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli?

Tags: angular, npm, openapi-generator

I use [@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli)(v2.1.7) to generate the API library on client side.

It works pretty well, except I am not able to format the code generated as I want.

I just noticed there is a new option that allows to configure the spaces as mentioned in the example (**"spaces": 2**):

```
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/config.schema.json",
  "spaces": 2,
  "generator-cli": {
    "version": "4.3.1",
    "storageDir": "~/my/custom/storage/dir", // optional
    "generators": { // optional
      "v2.0": { // any name you like (just printed to the console log) 
        "generatorName": "typescript-angular",
        "output": "#{cwd}/output/v2.0/#{ext}/#{name}",
        "glob": "examples/v2.0/{json,yaml}/*.{json,yaml}",
        "additionalProperties": {
          "ngVersion": "6.1.7",
          "npmName": "restClient",
          "supportsES6": "true",
          "npmVersion": "6.9.0",
          "withInterfaces": true
        }
      },
      "v3.0": { // any name you like (just printed to the console log) 
        "generatorName": "typescript-fetch",
        "output": "#{cwd}/output/v3.0/#{ext}/#{name}",
        "glob": "examples/v3.0/petstore.{json,yaml}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This sounds great!

The problem is that I am not able to use the configuration file as specified in the [official page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli):

> If openapi-generator-cli generate is called without further arguments, then the configuration is automatically used to generate your code.

When I do that:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate
```

I keep stuck with an error:

> [error] Required option '-i' is missing

And if I add the -i parameter, for example:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i http://localhost:8081/v2/api-docs
```

Then the "openapitools.json" file is ignored and overwritten by the default configuration:

```
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/config.schema.json",
  "spaces": 2,
  "generator-cli": {
    "version": "4.3.1"
  }
}
```

I also tried to do it the way I've used to do it up to now plus adding the parameter "-spaces=2":

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i http://localhost:8081/v2/api-docs -g typescript-angular -o src/app/tools/openapi -spaces=2
```

But again it didn't work, plus I have now a useless file (openapitools.json) annoying my obsessive-compulsive disorder!

For info, my npm version (npm -v) is:

> 6.14.8

And I am using the current last Angular version:

> 11.0.0

Comment: I think that the -i option is inside of your `v2.0 | v3.0` under key `"input-spec":"http://localhost:port/whatever"`

Answer (score 4):

You can try this, it will work

your `openapitools.json` content should be like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/config.schema.json",
  "spaces": 2,
  "generator-cli": {
    "version": "5.3.0",
     "generators":{
         "v2.0": {
        "generatorName": "javascript",
        "output": "./output",
        "inputSpec": "http://localhost:44301/swagger/v1/swagger.json",
        "additionalProperties": {
          "npmName": "restClient",
          "supportsES6": "true",
          "withInterfaces": true
        }
      }
     }
  }
}
```

I know based on the documentation here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli there should be a `"glob": "examples/v2.0/{json,yaml}/*.{json,yaml}",` under your generator key but for a strange reason, the `"glob"` will work with the file but not URLs!
if you want to get your Open API Specification file directly from Swagger URL in your API server you should use  `"inputSpec"` instead and it worked for me. in my case it is:

```
  "inputSpec": "http://localhost:44301/swagger/v1/swagger.json",
```

if you set your `openapitools.json` like above code you can generate for example your javascript client with this command:

```
 openapi-generator-cli generate  --generator-key v1.0
```

Comment: Is the generator key 'v1.0' correct? I guess it's a typo and should be 'v2.0', right?

Comment: you are right, thank you, it's a typo and should be v2.0

Answer (score 3):

I have had similar problems as described by you; in particular the "overwritten by the default configuration".

I do think that a non-valid opanapitools.json is causing it to be completely reset.
It seems like the comments are causing these validation errors.

Maybe remove them and try again.

Hope this helps, I got it running with package.json->scripts like this.

Although the "spaces" property seems only to be used, when the cli is writing it's own config file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will have a try as soon as I have some time. I ended up going back to an earlier version.

Comment: I had the same behavior. It was caused by an invalid Json file. Fixing the formal of the file fixed the problem.